# Google Groups integrating into website

Tags: html, css, google-groups

Does anybody have experience integrating google groups into a website?  Might be able to just pull it in via iframe or RSS recent posts but that's not really enough.

We are trying to make them serve like our websites forums but I can't figure out how.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try https://sites.google.com/site/embeddingdiscussions/using-iframes -- let me know how it goes.